# Get Return Code of SFTP command

Tags: unix, sftp, ksh

I have the snippet below inside my ksh script. Is there a way that I can have a return code whether the sftp executed successfully and copied the files from source to target destination?

```
echo "sftp start" >> /test/logfile.log
sftp user@server <<EOF >> /test/logfile.log
cd /tgt/files
lcd /src/files
rm *.csv
put -p *.csv
exit
EOF
echo "sftp end" >> /test/logfile.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do :

```
echo "sftp start" >> /test/logfile.log

sftp user@server <<EOF >> /test/logfile.log
cd /tgt/files
lcd /src/files
rm *.csv
put -p *.csv
exit
EOF

exit_code=$?

if [[ $exit_code != 0 ]]; then
    echo "sftp error" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "sftp end" >> /test/logfile.log
```

Comment: I can then terminate the script using this am I correct?

if [[ $exit_code -gt 0 ]];then 
 print "Error in SFTP Process"
 exit 1
fi

Answer (score 11):

The solution of Gilles Quenot will only work with the following three improvements. Without those improvement the exit status will always be 0 regardless the result of the sftp commands.

1. sftp option `-b -` needs to be added to the sftp command. Only then will sftp exit with status 1 if some sftp command goes wrong. Otherwise the exit status is always 0.
2. I've added `2>&1 | tee` to log also the errors (it redirects stderr to stdout)
3. You must use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to read the exit status of sftp. $? gives the exit status of the last command and that is the redirect to the logfile.

> ```
> echo "sftp start" >> /test/logfile.log
>
> sftp -b - user@server <<EOF 2>&1 | tee /test/logfile.log
> cd /tgt/files
> lcd /src/files
> rm *.csv
> put -p *.csv
> exit
> EOF
>
> exit_code=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
>
> if [[ $exit_code != 0 ]]; then
> echo "sftp error" >&2
> exit 1
> fi 
>
> echo "sftp end" >> /test/logfile.log
> ```

Regards,
Maarten

Comment: Adding "-b -"  works for me .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sftp` and writing so many intermediate commands in order to move to the proper folders, remove files etc before your transfer, you could use the following way more compact commands:

```
echo "file transfer started" >> /test/logfile.log
ssh user@server 'rm /tgt/files/*.csv' >> /test/logfile.log 2>&1 && scp /src/files/*.csv user@server:/tgt/files/ >> /test/logfile.log 2>&1

rc=$?

if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: transfer failed" >> /test/logfile.log
    exit 1
fi

echo "file transfer completed" >> /test/logfile.log
```

**Explanations:**

`ssh user@server 'rm /tgt/files/*.csv' >> /test/logfile.log 2>&1 && scp /src/files/*.csv user@server:/tgt/files/ >> /test/logfile.log 2>&1` if the files are properly removed from the target folder than and only than (`&&`) the transfer will be done!! Intermediate errors are also redirected to the output log files.